# To get logs in between particular time-stamps using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract infromation from logs using a shell script for a particular time range . A line in logs looks like this:

```
[14:58:27:176][15-10-2015]: testing1-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[14:59:27:178][15-10-2015]: testing2-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:00:27:179][15-10-2015]: testing3-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:01:27:180][15-10-2015]: testing4-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:01:27:181][15-10-2015]: testing5-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:182][15-10-2015]: testing6-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:183][15-10-2015]: testing7-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:184][15-10-2015]: testing8-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:191][15-10-2015]: testing9-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:192][15-10-2015]: testing10-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:193][15-10-2015]: testing11-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:208][15-10-2015]: testing12-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:04:27:209][15-10-2015]: testing13-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:49:27:210][15-10-2015]: testing14-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[13:02:17:209][15-10-2015]: testing13-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:04:27:209][16-10-2015]: testing13-vidya-Fri Oct 16 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:49:27:210][16-10-2015]: testing14-vidya-Fri Oct 16 11:49:27 IST 2015
```

I need to extract data in specific intervals. for example in between 14:59 to 15:03 on 15-10-2015 as shown below:

```
[14:59:27:178][15-10-2015]: testing2-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:00:27:179][15-10-2015]: testing3-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:01:27:180][15-10-2015]: testing4-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:01:27:181][15-10-2015]: testing5-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:182][15-10-2015]: testing6-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:183][15-10-2015]: testing7-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:184][15-10-2015]: testing8-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:02:27:191][15-10-2015]: testing9-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:192][15-10-2015]: testing10-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:193][15-10-2015]: testing11-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
[15:03:27:208][15-10-2015]: testing12-vidya-Thu Oct 15 11:49:27 IST 2015
```

I am new to shell script.I have tried with grep command . Can anyone suggest me how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sed`.

```
sed -n '/\[14:59/,/\[15:03/p' log
```

Update: remote via ssh

```
ssh user@remotehost.com "sed -n -e '/\[14:59/,/\[15:03/p' /var/logfile"
```

To only extract lines that were found between the times of interest on a specific date, include the date in your search string:

```
sed -n '/\[14:59.*15-10-2015*/,/\[15:03.*15-10-2015/p' log
```

Comment: @X Tian : sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated address regex error is coming

Comment: sshpass -p xxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xxx@HostIP 'cd Vidya;sed -n '/\[14:59/,/\[15:03/p'serverout  >>result'

Comment: If I executed separately it was wrking fine . But If I gave as above it is not working . Can you suggest me how to solve this ?

Comment: your single-quote marks are getting mixed up

Comment: Updated ans was helpful . Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Need to mention Date in that grep command .. any suggestions ?

Comment: grep -E "^\[(12:2[6-9]|12:3[0-9]|12:40)" | grep '\[19-10'  filename  : I tried this . I am getting all 19-10-2015 data including 12:26 to 12:40 .I need only data from 12.26 to 12.40. Is it correct , anythting wrong in this ?

Comment: You need to ask this as a new question. and provide input data example

Comment: @XTian not really, the difference is tiny and the OP basically posted a duplicate. I edited to match the day as well instead.

Comment: @Vidya I closed your question as a duplicate since it is very similar to what was asked here. Have a look at X Tian's updated answer and please remember to accept it if it solves your issue.

Comment: Sorry. I didnt see updated answer . As X Tian told ,asked as a new question.Sorry Once again. WIll remove that new question . By d way X Tian ans was helpful . Now going to close the thread . Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Vidya don't worry, you did nothing wrong. X Tian made a very reasonable suggestion, it is usually better to ask a new question than continue asking things in the comments. It's just that in this particular case, the questions are so similar, it's not worth doing so. Nobody did anything wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Grep which can use regular expressions, like this:

```
grep -E "^\[(14:59|15:00|15:01|15:02|15:03)" /path/to/file
```

Comment: Or, more concisely `grep -E "^\[(14:59|15:0[0-3])"`

Comment: yes this is working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Vidya If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.